# Edit while running with Typescript and Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

While using Typescript with Visual Studio 2013, I seem to recall that I could edit TypeScript source while running it in a browser window, then refresh the browser window and get the new changes.

Now, in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio disables editing while the browser window is open. That means I have to stop and restart once I want to edit the source. This seems pretty stupid to me since all it would need to do is recompile the source, which it does all the time anyways. :)

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is broken in the current CTP (5).

It's on their backlog though, vote for it on uservoice to help speed them along: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6926059-edit-and-continue-for-typescript

Answer (score 1):

I recently fixed this issue for a number of projects I've been working on and wanted to share what I did just in case it helps anyone else.

I eventually realised that after updating a TypeScript file whilst in debug mode would remove the source map reference from the JS file e.g:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=View.js.map
```

Once I made this discovery I was able to find a bug logged for it figure out the steps to resolve the issue here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5001

In summary what I did was right click the project file in Visual Studio, went to the TypeScript tab and un-ticked and re-ticked the option 'Generate source maps' (see below image) and then saved the project file.

[image]

I hope this helps others as much as it has me :)